# jquery conflicting issue with multiple jquery adding

Tags: jquery

I have one website, every thing is working fine.

now I want to add one contactable Jquery form and when I add below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

contact form work but other features of website like drop down stop working.

and when I remove above code every thing on website work fine expect this contact form.

I think there is conflict between jquerys, as I also have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(window).load(function(){jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fold',slices:15,boxCols:8,boxRows:8,animSpeed:500,pauseTime:5000,directionNav:true,directionNavHide:false,controlNav:false,captionOpacity:1});});</script>
```

any help how to make it working with both.

Comment: You're loading three different jQuery libraries? Why?

Comment: i dont know. this website is already using one JQUERY. i just add one contact jquery form

Answer (score 2):

If you must have two verisons of jQuery, you must use the jQuery noConflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/